# Why does phpmyadmin present an error 500 when trying to enter Designer?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> Error in processing request
>   Error code: 500
>   Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)
>   It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.

Hey Guys! I am getting the error described in the title when trying to access "designer" tab in phpmyadmin. I already attempted to change the storage, post_max_size and all those stuff but nothing has happened. Any advice?

This is what php_error.logs shows me:

/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/db_designer.php(190): PhpMyAdmin\Database\Designer->getHtmlTableList(NULL, NULL)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sik1l.png

Comment: What does your server's error log tell you about this?

Comment: #0 /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/db_designer.php(190): PhpMyAdmin\Database\Designer->getHtmlTableList(NULL, NULL)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Database/Designer.php on line 290

Comment: Well, looks like you should approach their support. That does not look like a programming question

Comment: Who do you mean by "their"?

Comment: That looks like a bug of phpMyAdmin, and "their" means their contributors

Comment: Would you recommend me deleting MAMP and installing it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing line 268 to `return array();` worked for me

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/e1021b109b2f6292e44472063f951691cd55b248

Answer (score 0):

Remove all index and recreates the indexes

for example
ALTER TABLE `tableName` DROP INDEX `rowName`;

ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD INDEX(`rowName`);