# Getting an Error 500 on php myadmin using MAMP and a MAC

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm using a MAC OS and I have MAMP installed. I  have set up my database in PHP myAdmin however when I go into Designer tab to set up my relationships, I get Error 500.

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf/php.ini` <- Version I'm running

[image: Error 500 Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot of myAdmin page]

Thank you all (sorry I haven't given a more technical description I'm a newby.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does phpmyadmin present an error 500 when trying to enter Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227840/why-does-phpmyadmin-present-an-error-500-when-trying-to-enter-designer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone already suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227840/why-does-phpmyadmin-present-an-error-500-when-trying-to-enter-designer) all you have to do is to open

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Database/Designer/Common.php
```

And on line 268 edit from 
`return null;` to `return array();`